# How to scale image out of div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to scale image on hover using css,

here is my code

HTML:

```
<div class="cli-wrap">
<ul class="clearfix" id="ci-list" style="width: 2640px;">
    <li style="margin-left: 0px;" class="zoomage"><a target="_blank" href="#"><img border="0" src="images/1.png"></a></li>
    <li style="margin-left: 0px;" class="zoomage"><a target="_blank" href="#"><img border="0" src="images/2.png"></a></li>
    <li style="margin-left: 0px;" class="zoomage"><a target="_blank" href="#"><img border="0" src="images/3.png"></a></li>
    <li style="margin-left: 0px;" class="zoomage"><a target="_blank" href="#"><img border="0" src="images/4.png"></a></li>
    <li style="margin-left: 0px;" class="zoomage"><a target="_blank" href="#"><img border="0" src="images/5.png"></a></li>
    <li style="margin-left: 0px;" class="zoomage"><a target="_blank" href="#"><img border="0" src="images/6.png"></a></li>
    <li style="margin-left: 0px;" class="zoomage"><a target="_blank" href="#"><img border="0" src="images/7.png"></a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.zoomage:hover img {
    -webkit-transform:scale(7.10); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(7.10); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(7.10); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(7.10); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(7.10);
    z-index:1;
}

.cli-wrap {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 620px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

here the image is scaling on hover but, the image is scaling within  the div .cli-wrap.
the image is scaling to big size but it is only scaling inside the div. but i need to scale  the image outside the div. i tried using the z-index for div .cli-wrap

how can i do this?

Comment: Please also add the CSS which you're using for `<div class="cli-wrap">`

Comment: @FahadHasan I have added the css for cli-wrap also.

Comment: Buddy it just clipped out because of `overflow: hidden` property in `.cli-wrap`

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this result in a far more simpler way:

Instead of this:

```
.zoomage:hover img {
-webkit-transform:scale(7.10); /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transform:scale(7.10); /* Firefox */
-ms-transform:scale(7.10); /* IE 9 */
-o-transform:scale(7.10); /* Opera */
 transform:scale(7.10);
z-index:1;
}
```

I did

```
.zoomage:hover{
    width:1848px;
   /*somevalue here, you chose what u want here, ie the scaled down image*/
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes i tried using width ealier,but all other images got collapsed.

Comment: just wondering, where exactly do u want the images to pop up?

Comment: b/c "outside of the div isnt specific enough"

Comment: i have a div. inside that div i have list of images. when hovered on those images , the images are scaling up, the scaling up is happening within the div. the scaled image looks like half cut. it should appear full over of the div.

Comment: I got it resolved. i couldn't figure it out, but instead added jquery popup.


Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can give the image absolute position so it will look out of the div like so :

```
 .zoomage:hover img {
                position: absolute;
                overflow: hidden;
                top:300px;
                left:300px;
                transition: all 1s ease;
                -webkit-transform:scale(7.10); /* Safari and Chrome */
                -moz-transform:scale(7.10); /* Firefox */
                -ms-transform:scale(7.10); /* IE 9 */
                -o-transform:scale(7.10); /* Opera */
                transform:scale(7.10);
                z-index:1;


            }
```