# CSS object-position or similar property for a photo grid

Tags: html, css, image, properties, css-position

Hoping to get some input. I've been taking some online courses on web development and I've been currently playing around adding images to an html page (3x3 image grid).

First I used the transform property so I could scale the image with a .5s transition to 1.5 times the size after hovering over it with a .5 second delay.

There is an issue with the images on the left and right sides as part of them go out of the screen after scaling.

To correct this I first tried `position: relative; left: 6%;` but learned that position is not a property you can animate, so the image immediately moves position and then scales after .5 seconds.

My second try was with `object-position: 90px;` , this property does work with the delay but after it scales it seems like a big chunk of the image is cropped.

I've been trying different properties like transform-origin which kind of works but gives it a glitchy feeling as it scales and then finishes moving the image to the side losing fluidity.

Can't seem to find  helpful documentation on object-position as to why part of the image crops, this property gives a fluid scaling and positioning effect but I have that cropping issue.

Here is a link to a codepen where I have this exercise:

https://codepen.io/superavd88/pen/PoqYoRJ

Any ideas would be really appreciated as I've been trying to fix this issue for the last couple of days without success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO!May be this could help you wrap you images inside some `div` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601961/how-to-scale-image-out-of-div this link question is what you need

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

> You just need to wrap you images indie `div` and make it overflow
>   `hidden` and also i changed the grid, using `flex` now

```css
.thumbnail img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    width:100%;
}
.thumbnail .img-parent:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
}

.img-parent{
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 33%;
}
img{
width: 100%}
.thumbnail {
    display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="img-parent">
         <img src="https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-apps/imrs.php?src=https://arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/HB4AT3D3IMI6TMPTWIZ74WAR54.jpg&w=767" alt="deep house cleaning">
             </div>
      
  
    <div class="img-parent">
         <img src="https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-apps/imrs.php?src=https://arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/HB4AT3D3IMI6TMPTWIZ74WAR54.jpg&w=767" alt="deep house cleaning">
             </div>
      
 
    <div class="img-parent">
         <img src="https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-apps/imrs.php?src=https://arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/HB4AT3D3IMI6TMPTWIZ74WAR54.jpg&w=767" alt="deep house cleaning">
             </div>
      
 
    <div class="img-parent">
         <img src="https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-apps/imrs.php?src=https://arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/HB4AT3D3IMI6TMPTWIZ74WAR54.jpg&w=767" alt="deep house cleaning">
             </div>
      
    </div>
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) for how `scale` property work

Answer (score 0):

change CSS styles

```
  img   {
    width: 30%;
    float: initial;
    margin: 1rem;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

  .leftimg:hover{
      transform: scale(1.5);

  }

  .rightimg:hover{
      transform: scale(1.5);
  }

  .center:hover{
      transform: scale(1.5);
  }
```